# OrientDB throws OStorageException on list databases command

Tags: java, orientdb, orientdb2.2

Here is a command I am using:

> orientdb> CONNECT remote:192.168.0.12 root password
>
> Connecting to remote Server instance [remote:192.168.0.12] with user 'root'...OK
>
> orientdb {server=remote:192.168.0.12/}>  LIST DATABASES

Console output:

> Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot retrieve the configuration list
>
> Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

What doest that mean and how can it be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try connecting from the server host where the server is hosted? So we can exclude network problems.

Comment: I guess `Connecting to remote Server instance [remote:192.168.0.12] with user 'root'...OK` means that there is no network/connection problem, doesn't it?

Comment: have you tried connecting via plocal?